# SpringBoot 1.2.1 MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm with the problem below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ANACDetailManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository com.almundo.anac.core.ANACDetailManager._repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.almundo.anac.service.AppInitializer.main(AppInitializer.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository com.almundo.anac.core.ANACDetailManager._repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
```

SpringConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg value="databaseName" />
  </bean>

  <mongo:repositories base-package="com.almundo.anac.core" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />

</beans>
```

AnacDetailManager.java:

```
    package com.almundo.anac.core;

import com.almundo.anac.domain.ANACDelay;
import com.almundo.anac.core.ANACDelayRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ANACDetailManager {

    @Autowired
    public MongoRepository<ANACDelay, String> _repository;

    public ANACDelay FindDelay(String flightNumber, String airCia, String origin, String destination) {
        String key = airCia + flightNumber + origin + destination;
        ANACDelay anacDelay = _repository.findOne(key);

        return anacDelay;
    }
}
```

AnacServiceController.java:

```
package com.almundo.anac.service.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.almundo.anac.core.ANACDetailManager;
import com.almundo.anac.domain.ANACDelay;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("anacservice")
//@ComponentScan("com.almundo.anac.core")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.almundo.anac.core")
public class AnacServiceController {

    @Autowired
    final ANACDetailManager _manager;

    @Autowired
    public AnacServiceController(ANACDetailManager manager) {
        this._manager = manager;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "{flightNumber}/{airCia}/{origin}/{destination}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ANACDelay> getAnacDelay(@PathVariable String flightNumber, @PathVariable String airCia,
            @PathVariable String origin, @PathVariable String destination) {

        ANACDelay anacDelay = _manager.FindDelay(flightNumber, airCia, origin, destination);

        return new ResponseEntity<ANACDelay>(anacDelay, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Just to explain, I'm building an Rest API that will call my repository to read data from the database.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Solve the problem. I've put @EnableMongoRepository in the AppInitializer.java:

```
package com.almundo.anac.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.almundo.anac.core", "com.almundo.anac.service"})
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.almundo.anac.core")
public class AppInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AppInitializer.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I solved the problem: I changed the place of the annotation @EnableMongoRepository to the AppInitializer.java.

Comment: You can (and should) add an answer to your question instead of editing the question w/ a solution.  Bonus: you get to accept your own answer, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the repository interface for your domain.

```
public interface YourRepository extends MongoRepository<ANACDelay, String> {}
```

and autowired this repository into manager.

Comment: I've tried this manner, but the problem still happening. See below code:

`code`
                        package com.almundo.anac.core;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import com.almundo.anac.domain.ANACDelay;


public interface ANACDelayRepository extends MongoRepository<ANACDelay, String> {
 
}
`code`

Comment: Try removing the EnableMongoRepositories annotation. It's redundant as it is already mentioned in the xml config. Everything else looks okay to me. Make sure to autowire this repository in the manager.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface inside package com.almundo.anac.core

```
package com.almundo.anac.core;

public interface ANACDelayRepository extends MongoRepository<ANACDelay, String> {

}
```

Then ANACDetailManager should be like this:

```
@Service
public class ANACDetailManager {

    @Autowired
    public ANACDelayRepository _repository;

    public ANACDelay FindDelay(String flightNumber, String airCia, String origin, String destination) {
        String key = airCia + flightNumber + origin + destination;
        ANACDelay anacDelay = _repository.findOne(key);

        return anacDelay;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this manner, but the problem still happening. See below code: 

`code`
    package com.almundo.anac.core;

    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
    import com.almundo.anac.domain.ANACDelay;


    public interface ANACDelayRepository extends MongoRepository<ANACDelay, String> {
 
    }
`code`

Comment: Did you add <import resource="SpringConfig.xml" /> inside your applicationContext.xml? Or if you are using java configuration add @ImportResource("classpath:SpringConfig.xml") in your configuration class. Make sure to change path if it differs in your project directory structure.

Comment: Thank you for your help!